# Angular querystring parameter with a hash in it

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I'm fairly new to angular and especially the routing portion.  I'm using using `angular-routing` and am passing over a querystring parameter that has a hash in it.  When I do this, `$routeParams` only picks up the characters before the hash.

Is there a good way to deal with this?

Routes where `:battle_tag` is name#number, like `pizza#7777`.

```
var diabloApp = angular.module('diabloApp', ['ngRoute']);

diabloApp.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/heroes/:id/:battle_tag', {
        controller: 'heroesController',
        templateUrl: '../templates/Heroes.html'
    })
    .otherwise({
        controller: 'homeController',
        templateUrl: '../templates/Index.html'
    })
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

I've been looking for good ways to encode this but it's really not an encoding issue.  I realize separate it on from the hrefs but it really would be a pain and doesn't seem a great way to do it.

Any input is appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: are all `:battle_tag` parameters structured like this, `text#text`?

Comment: @ryeballar Yes, unfortunately.

Comment: if so, why don't you separate it like this, `/heroes/:id/:battle_tag_name/:battle_tag_number` instead

Comment: @ryeballar Yeah, good idea.  I did it and it works well, thanks.  But does this mean that if I ever have a query string parameter with a hash I have to split it?

Comment: Yes, it seems you have to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate the `:battle_tag` parameter into two parts instead:

`/heroes/:id/:battle_tag_name/:battle_tag_number`

This way, AngularJS' **[`$routeProvider`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider)** detects the route as it is.